# Django ORM join with another table

Tags: django, orm

I have a table known as `messages`. In my application, users can send different *type* of messages. Like forwarding an event, etc. As such, I have columns `type` and `value` in that table.

What I want to do is for a particular `type`, goto a particular table and make sure the `value` is valid (typically this maps to the `id` of that table). There could be multiple types, and each one has to be mapped to a different table. Is there a way to logically write this in the built in django ORM? Right now I'm only seeing this feasible if I use straight SQL, which I would rather not if I can get away with it...

Right now I'm doing something like:

```
Messages.objects.all().filter(Q(user_id=id))...etc
```

I want to add to the statement above checking the `type` and for the particular `type`, check the table associated with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a "polymorphic association".  There are a couple ways to do analogous things in Django, but I think the one that most closely matches what you described is the [contenttypes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) module, which uses separate columns for the type and for the value as in your application.

Comment: No..don't think that's it. Because my `type` column can map to a few types of tables, not just one... So the `value` column would have to use the table based on `type`...does that make sense?

Comment: That sounds exactly like what contenttypes is for.  A polymorphic association is when you have a foreign key that can point to a row in any one of a number of tables, instead of just pointing to a row in a single predefined table.  Look at the "generic relations" section of the documentation I linked.

Comment: Are u sure? Sorry for more questions. But say `type` is 'E', I want it to check an `event` table, if it's 'M', I want it to check `value` in `user` table...

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what contenttypes does -- except that it automatically manages the "type" column so you won't have to do explicit mapping between "E" and `event` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You may just want to define a [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) structure.  This gets you the same result in that you have multiple types of messages and field inheritance, but you don't have to mess with a `type` field at all.

```
class Message(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=9000)

class Event(Message):
    pass

class Tweet(Message):
    pass
```

In view post handler:

```
...
if request.POST['type'] == 'event':
    Event.objects.create(value=request.POST['value'])
elif request.POST['type'] == 'tweet':
    Tweet.objects.create(value=request.POST['value'])
...
```

Then, get your objects:

```
all_tweets = Tweet.objects.all()
all_messages = Message.objects.all()

for message in all_messages:
    try:
        event = message.event
    except Event.DoesNotExist:
        # this message is not an Event
        pass
```

If this sort of structure doesn't work for you, there are two other styles of Model inheritance supported by Django: [Abstract base classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) and [Proxy models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models). You could also hold a [GenericForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#id1) as suggested by @AndrewGorcester.